# Salesforce button uses same Docusign template regardless of related Opportunity

Tags: javascript, salesforce, docusignapi

when I use the button, the same Docusign template is used regardless of the associated Opportunity.  If I move the (OPPNAME = 'WorldQuant LLC%') line to the end, a different template is used, but again its the same regardless of Opportunity Name.  I am new to Javascript so feel free to dumb down any answers, thanks.

```
var OPPNAME; 
var PICKDSTEMPLATE; 
OPPNAME == '{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Name)}'; 
PICKDSTEMPLATE = '{!Opportunity.Type_of_Opportunity__c}'; 
if (OPPNAME = 'WorldQuant LLC%') 
{ 
DST = '75E95019-6513-4EE9-8f6B-C2FD9A99B9C2'; 
} 
else if (OPPNAME != 'WorldQuant LLC%' && PICKDSTEMPLATE == 'Corp/Ind') 
{ 
DST='38FE916A-0F28-46FD-BBAB-28CA54621B7E'; 
} 
else if (OPPNAME != 'WorldQuant LLC%' && PICKDSTEMPLATE == 'Corporate from Lead') 
{ 
DST = 'ACB0C25C-38FE-4802-9BEA-8CA5D8AA77A9'; 
} 
else if (OPPNAME != 'WorldQuant LLC%' && PICKDSTEMPLATE == 'Corporate') 
{ 
DST = 'ACB0C25C-38FE-4802-9BEA-8CA5D8AA77A9'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work with some help:

```
var ACCNAME; 
var PICKDSTEMPLATE; 
ACCNAME = '{!Opportunity.Account}'; 
PICKDSTEMPLATE = '{!Opportunity.Type_of_Opportunity__c}'; 
if ((ACCNAME == 'WorldQuant LLC') && (PICKDSTEMPLATE == 'Corp/Ind' || PICKDSTEMPLATE == 'Corporate')) 
{ 
DST = '75e95019-6513-4ee9-8f6b-c2fd9a99b9c2'; 
} 
else if ((ACCNAME != 'WorldQuant LLC') && (PICKDSTEMPLATE == 'Corp/Ind')) 
{ 
DST='38FE916A-0F28-46FD-BBAB-28CA54621B7E'; 
} 
else if ((ACCNAME != 'WorldQuant LLC') && (PICKDSTEMPLATE == 'Corporate from Lead')) 
{ 
DST = 'ACB0C25C-38FE-4802-9BEA-8CA5D8AA77A9'; 
} 
else if ((ACCNAME != 'WorldQuant LLC') && (PICKDSTEMPLATE == 'Corporate')) 
{ 
DST = 'ACB0C25C-38FE-4802-9BEA-8CA5D8AA77A9'; 
}
```